# Parsing TimeSpan from string including format

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, timespan

I'm sure this must be simple, but I can't figure out how to word it correctly in Google...

I have a config which has a field:

```
TimeToPoll="1d"
```

Now I want to do something **like**:

```
TimeSpan.Parse(TimeToPoll);
```

Returning a timespan of one day.

In C#

EDIT:
I'm looking for a method which allows parse of "1d" as well as "1s" or "1y" etc. Is this possible?

Meaning:

```
     "1d" parses to {1.00:00:00}
     "1h" parses to {0.01:00:00}
     "1m" parses to {0.00:01:00}
     "1s" parses to {0.00:00:01}
```

Comment: My apologies, I have updated.

Comment: check this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days.aspx

Comment: Just translate the string in the setting to a format string that TimeSpan.TryParse() accepts.  Or change the setting string itself.  Watch out of .NET dependency, TryParse() is only available in .NET 4.

Comment: Okay thanks. I may figure out a work around for this. As it would make the config much simpler to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `d` is not needed and is the reason your parse fails.

```
var oneDay = TimeSpan.Parse("1");
```

---

Update:

For what you are looking to do, there is no built in support. You would need to write your own parser.

Comment: This would need -
TimeSpan.FromDays(double.Parse("1"));

Comment: @MatthewCanty - I don't follow. What I have written is valid.

Comment: Ah, so it does. Sorry. I just didn't think something so ambiguous could happen. I assumed it would have returned the smallest possible value.

Answer (score 5):

This is my resolution:

```
    public static TimeSpan ConvertToTimeSpan(this string timeSpan)
    {
        var l = timeSpan.Length - 1;
        var value = timeSpan.Substring(0, l);
        var type = timeSpan.Substring(l, 1);

        switch (type)
        {
            case "d": return TimeSpan.FromDays(double.Parse(value));
            case "h": return TimeSpan.FromHours(double.Parse(value));
            case "m": return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(double.Parse(value));
            case "s": return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double.Parse(value));
            case "f": return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(double.Parse(value));
            case "z": return TimeSpan.FromTicks(long.Parse(value));
            default: return TimeSpan.FromDays(double.Parse(value));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should store your values in your config file in one of the formats that [TimeSpan.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx) can work with.  There are several samples on that page.

EDIT:  The examples are in the code toward the bottom of the page.