# Error converting value \"1D\" to type 'System.Int64' while desalinizing JSON object to data table

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonserializer

I am trying to deserialize jsonoutput to the data table and getting the below error

Error converting value "1D" to type 'System.Int64'

I am using this - > JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(jSonOutput)

Data in the input column is similar to like this.

Column0
12
13
14
1D
12M

Comment: You need to work on this question, Paste the actual json, or part there of. Paste the actual code, and the actual error message. Describe what you are actually trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column0 seems to contain string representations of timespans (1d = 1 day, 12M = 12 months).

You cannot deserialize this into an integer as it contains characters.
Your target variable type should rather be a timespan. But then you also cannot easily deserialize these kind of strings.

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10228041/5018895) to a helper function that could probably work...